# Not Implemented Exception when trying to load a single entity with LINQ on EF Core?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, mocking, entity-framework-core

I am writing my own tests to mock entity framework on .NET core, however I have been having some trouble as some LINQ queries work fine and others throw a not implemented exception. This is the basic query guide I have been using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/basic

Here is an example of the problem with two tests. The first uses the ToList() query to load all data, and tests against the first and only entity. This works but is not ideal. The second test attempts to grab the specific entity using its Id, following the guide's 'Loading a single entity' instructions. However, this one throws the exception.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_AddBook()
    {
        // Arrange
        var context = new TestContext();
        var service = new BookStore(context);

        // Act
        service.AddBook(1, "Wuthering Heights", "Emily Brontë", "Classics", 7.99, 5);

        //Assert
        var books = context.Books.ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(books[0].Title, "Wuthering Heights");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_AddBook2()
    {
        // Arrange
        var context = new TestContext();
        var service = new BookStore(context);

        // Act
        service.AddBook(1, "Wuthering Heights", "Emily Brontë", "Classics", 7.99, 5);

        //Assert
        var book = context.Books.Single(b => b.Id == 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(book.Title, "Wuthering Heights");
    }
```

The debugger shows the id of the book in the context to be 1:

[image]

And the code for TestContext:

```
class TestContext : IBookContext
{
    public TestContext()
    {
        this.Books = new TestDbSet<Book>();
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public int SaveChangesCount { get; private set; }
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.SaveChangesCount++;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is the tutorial I have been following, with a few things changed to adapt it to .NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/writing-test-doubles

Comment: what is the value of the Id of the book in the context.Books collection in the second test, while debugging?

Comment: Which is the exception? The single method throws an exception if not exactly one element satisfies your condition ( in your case ID ).

Comment: @Matt.G the value of the id of the book in the context is shown to be 1 in the debugger, I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @TiagoSilva the exception reads "System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'".

Comment: Can you show us the code for `TestContext`?

Comment: @jpgrassi I have added the TestContext class to the question above, as well as a link to the tutorial I had been using as a mock testing reference.